# Do crew receiving a better offer bring their gear with them?

Tags: firefly

> **A Better Offer**
>
> Other players may hire Disgruntled
> Crew away from you when in the
> same Sector by paying their hiring
> fee to the bank. The Disgruntled crew
> joins their new Captain’s crew and the
> Disgruntled token is removed.

Do crew receiving a better offer bring their gear with them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There really isn't a definitive ruling on this anywhere within the rules or the FAQ.

However the [FAQ](http://www.flamesofwar.com/Portals/0/all_images/GF9/Firefly/Rulebooks/FAQ/Firefly_FAQ_v3.pdf) does state

> The only time you may not switch Gear is during a Work Action. Other than that, you may change who is carrying what Gear freely.

Based on this I would rule that you are absolutely entitled to strip any Gear off a character before they are taken from your ship.